# Reading XML by Dataset

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I using a dataset to read an xml file as shown below
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml("C:\test.xml");

test.xml contains

```
<MasterEntities>
  <FieldInfo>
    <Name>OMID</Name>
    <Mandatory>Yes</Mandatory>
    <RangeName>AssumptOMID</RangeName>
    <DataType>int</DataType>
    <Length>10</Length>
  </FieldInfo>
  <FieldInfo>
    <Name>ClientName</Name>
    <Mandatory>Yes</Mandatory>
    <RangeName>AssumptClient</RangeName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <Length>50</Length>
  </FieldInfo>
  <FieldInfo>
    <Name>OppName</Name>
    <Mandatory>Yes</Mandatory>
    <RangeName>AssumptProjectName</RangeName>
    <DataType>string</DataType>
    <Length>50</Length>
  </FieldInfo>

  <Settings>
    <somesetting1></somesetting1>
    <somesetting2></somesetting2>
  </Settings>
</MasterEntities>
```

now i want to read fieldInfo in one dataset/datatable and settings in another dataset/datatable

Please help me with the code

Comment: The XML data is in-comprehensive as the tags are missing. Put the XML inside a code block in the post please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a toy app that does that same thing, and shows the tables in the DataSet in a tree - and the contents of the table in a grid ... handy for seeing what's in a simple XML file ...
http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/WTFXMLSetup_1_8_0.msi.

Source to the VB.NET project if you want it ... http://www.dot-dash-dot.com/files/wtfxml.zip

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadXml to load your file into a single dataset. Your XML as displayed will read into 2 tables: one called FieldInfo, and the other called Settings.

```
string fileName = @"C:\Temp\sample.xml";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(fileName);
```

To move the second table into a new DataSet, you can do something like this

```
DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
ds2.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[1].Copy()); // copy to second dataset
ds.Tables.RemoveAt(1); // remove the original table
```